# Why Count doesn't works when grouping?

Tags: sql, group-by

I found it weird that when I do the count(*) for a group based on CASE WHEN, the simple query doesn't work.

I have to create a temp_ table to get the job done.

I use DbVisualizer Free 10.0.8 [Build #2841]

Can you please help explain what happens?

Thanks,

Hari

```
--this one NOT works
select (case when n_case IN ('1','2','3','4') then 'group1'
                else 'group2' end) as groupid, count(*)
from mytable
group by groupid
order by groupid;

--this one NOT works
select groupid, count(*)
from
        (select (case when n_case IN ('1','2','3','4') then 'group1'
                        else 'group2' end) as groupid, count(*)
        from mytable)
group by groupid
order by groupid;


--This one works
with temp_ as (select (case when n_case IN ('1','2','3','4') then 'group1'
                else 'group2' end) as groupid, *
                from mytable
              )
select groupid, count(*)
from temp_
group by groupid
order by groupid;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? What do you mean with "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 1):

SQL statement parsing sequence works in this way. You just don't have a column with name "groupid" at the time of grouping rows (only "n_case" is there for the moment).
That's why it is working properly with subquery (when when column "groupid"
has been already formed).

A little bit fixed your 2nd query (I have removed count(*) from subquery):

```
select groupid, count(*)
from
    (select (case when n_case IN ('1','2','3','4') then 'group1'
                    else 'group2' end) as groupid  
    from mytable) f
group by groupid
order by groupid;
```

or try this:

```
select case when n_case IN ('1','2','3','4') then 'group1'
            else 'group2' end groupid, count(*)
from mytable
group by case when n_case IN ('1','2','3','4') then 'group1'
            else 'group2' end  
order by 1;
```

[SQL Fiddle to play around](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fc1abb/1)